# WebSite Ajax navigation doesn't work when refreshing / share link

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm building a website with ajax navigation, so the whole site doesn't need to load everytime a user wants to see another page. Home, about, news, contact, etc...

I did built it, with `url`refresh, back button, everything ok.
But i have the following problem.

---

**Compartilhar/Refresh:**
When i refresh the page or share the link with someone, the website doesn't load properly. It only loads that specifc portion of the site. Example: If i share the link `mysite.com/about.php` it will only load the text of that page with no header, footer, and other common element from the main layout. Also with no `css`.
Same thing happens if i refresh the page when i'm in other page.

I tried to follow this [tutorial here](https://css-tricks.com/rethinking-dynamic-page-replacing-content/) but it doesn't load anything. Just give me a blank space.

The code i have below is working, but with the problem i've described above.

---

Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var content = $('#site'),
        firstLink = $(".navbar li:first-child a").attr("href"),
        navLink = $(".navbar li a");

    content.load(firstLink); //default load

    navLink.on("click", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        var newLink = $(this).attr("href");

         History.pushState(null, newLink, newLink);

        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        content.load(newLink, function () {
            FB.XFBML.parse();
        });

    });

    History.Adapter.bind(window, "statechange", function() {
        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        $("a[href='" + History.getState().title + "']").addClass("active");
        content.load(document.location.href); 
    });
});
```

Website structure code:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <!-- more code in here -->
    </header>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="active" href="/content/home.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/content/services.php">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="/content/people.php">People</a></li>
                <li><a href="/content/about.php">About us</a></li>
                <li><a href="/content/news.php">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="/content/contact.php">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="site"></div>
    <footer>
        <!-- more code in here -->
    </footer>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/history.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Cookie way:**

- Create a session expire cookie.
- When someone request a page and **have** this cookie send only the portion of the page.

but

- If when someone request a page and **haven't** this cookie. Set the session cookie and send ALL the index page + the extra content.

---

Example:

**1.** I request services.php and **have the cookie X**. The server will send only services.php

**2.** I request services.php and **haven't the cookie X**. The server will send the index.php and in the index.php you can make and include of services.php like:

```
//some html
if (!$_COOKIE["some_cookie_name"]) {
    include_once("the_page.php");
}
//more html
```

**3.** If i request `/` the server will only send the index.php

If you do an include from a parameter of the URL take care about what can they type and what you do with that.

**javascript (jQuery) way:**

- *Step 1.* Check in PHP if the call is a normal GET or an AJAX GET (http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ajax). You can do it in a multiple ways.

  - If the call is AJAX. Serve the portion of page.
  - If the call is NOT AJAX. Serve the index.php
- *Step 2.* Include in your index.php a javascript that check for the contents of the URL and then check the contents of a specific div like...:

  - If the URL is services.php and the content of div `#yourdiv` is empty --> Do an ajax call to services.php.
  - If the URL is `/` or the content of div `#yourdiv` isn't empty --> Do nothing.

**javascript (jQuery) + Cookie way:**

- *Step 1.* Check in PHP if the call is a normal GET or an AJAX GET (http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ajax). You can do it in a multiple ways.

  - If the call is AJAX. Serve the portion of page.
  - If the call is NOT AJAX. Serve the index.php and set some cookie name to your desired page (ex: services.php).
- *Step 2.* Include in your index.php a javascript that check if the cookie you created (or not) before exist...:

  - If the cookie exist --> Do an ajax call to the url in the cookie value & delete the cookie.
  - If the cookie not exist --> Just do nothing.

Hope it helps

Comment: But with this i would have to create an if for each page? Do you know if it's possible to do with ajax/jquery? I don' t know that much of php. What would be the 'some_cookie' part? Thanks